# MySQL Insert/Update Trigger with AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I've got a table roughly as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    CUSTID              INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME                CHAR (45),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (CUSTID))
AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

I'm auto incrementing the `CUSTID` so that it's possible to simply insert a name and have it created with the next available `CUSTID`. However, I also want to ensure that it isn't possible to set the `CUSTID` value to zero, either on creation of the row or on update so I've constructed the following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `custid_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `CUSTOMER`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.CUSTID) <= 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Check constraint on CUSTOMER.CUSTID failed';
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE TRIGGER `custid_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `CUSTOMER`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.CUSTID) <= 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Check constraint on CUSTOMER.CUSTID failed';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately in my blissful ignorance of how `AUTO_INCREMENT` worked, I've come to the conclusion that this is the wrong way to go about this. Trying to insert a customer with no `CUSTID` value is tripping the trigger causing the insert to fail which I presume is due to the value being a zero before insertion when `AUTO_INCREMENT` assigns it a value.

Would the best way to do this really be to change the trigger to occur after the insert and delete the row or is there a better way to do this to just throw an error?

Comment: Normally you'd use a CHECK constraint for this like `CHECK(custid > 0)` but..."*The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.*"
Unless there's a specific business reason why an ID can't be 0, there's no data integrity reason to disallow it.

Comment: Gotta love MySQL huh? It's unfortunately my spec with this that the ID can't ever be allowed to be below 1. The original Postgres I'm porting from actually uses a check exactly as you've suggested which works fine but I'm struggling to do the same with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert trigger is not needed.

From [Auto_Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

E.G.

```
create table t(id int auto_increment, primary key(id));
insert into t(id) values (0);
select id from t;
# 1
```

**Update:**

To allow the insert to complete when CUSTID is not specified,

```
INSERT INTO customer(name) VALUES('Chuck');
```

check for null in the trigger:

```
IF NEW.CUSTID IS NOT NULL AND NEW.CUSTID <= 0 THEN
```

Comment: Removing the insert trigger of course does get rid of the error, but it sort of defeats the object. I'm still able to do an insert of a `CUSTID` of `-12` or something similar which is what I'm trying to prevent. I'm working under the assumption that the user of the database will try this sort of thing and it must be handled somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: You could modify your existing insert trigger to check for NULL, then when CUSTID is not specified it will get the auto_increment value, otherwise it cannot be 0 or less.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting '0' into an auto-increment column causes it to increment the same as inserting NULL, so you really neither need nor want the INSERT trigger. Try it with just the UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Removing the insert trigger of course does get rid of the error, but it sort of defeats the object. I'm still able to do an insert of a `CUSTID` of `-12` or something similar which is what I'm trying to prevent. I'm working under the assumption that the user of the database will try this sort of thing and it must be handled somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a declarative constraint `CHECK (custid >= 0)`.

Comment: I don't believe MySQL supports using `CHECK` and has no alternative :(

Comment: Oh, yeah, MySQL. :P  I know MySQL permits declaring CHECK constraints even if it maybe still doesn't enforce them. You could try it and see what happens.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Just have your triggers check for custid < 0 instead of custid <= 0.